# A tiny creature wrapped in slime

Tags: riddle

A tiny creature wrapped in slime 
A useful little parasite 
I'll take your food and drink your wine 
I'll ask for more and you'll oblige.

Not a tapeworm. No, not quite. 
'Twould be ironic! This is why: 
In tapeworms I as well reside. 
Now the question: **What am I**?

Hint 1:

> I'm real. I'm not a creature from a fantasy movie or story.

Comment: "On tapeworms I as well reside. " Just to clarify, this is saying that it is something that lives on a tapeworm right?

Comment: @DigitalChris Yeah. I changed the wording to "In" instead of "On" so it will make more sense.

Comment: OK, because except for the tapeworm line, I was going to say "a baby" ;).

Comment: @LcIII please change your title.  This is the most vague riddle title I have ever seen.

Comment: Well done, but the first line is a problem. Maybe "A beast hiding in the warm and wet." It's still misleading, but more factual.

Comment: @TravisKindred The title is fine as it stands.  It doesn't reveal the solution, but allows users browsing the question list to be curious as to what the puzzle is. As it stands, I find the puzzle fine now, good job on LCIII to update it.

Comment: **Please remember that answers need to _explain why they are correct,_ not just answer the question.** Answers that don't explain why they are correct are of very low quality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> A stomach?
>  Tapeworms (I assume) have some sort of this, it will receive whatever you give it, it is certainly slimy, although not necessarily tiny.

Comment: And when it asks (grumbles) for more, you'll oblige. Good job.

Comment: Your stomach is a "loathsome little parasite"? Try having it removed....

Comment: @DigitalChris Good point. I've updated it. Please delete your comment since you're showing the answer to the world :D

Comment: I see this answer is accepted, but it's wrong because it ignores a facet of tapeworm anatomy. I'm being vague because I'm trying not to give the answer away, but a quick Google for tapeworm anatomy will reveal the flaw in the answer.

Comment: Stomach is neither a creature nor a parasite.

Comment: Stomachs are not always tiny. Stomachs are not a creature. Stomachs are not a parasite. Stomachs are not inside a tapeworm. "However, there is no digestive tract; the worm absorbs the host's digested food through its cuticle, or outer covering."

 http://www.infoplease.com/encyclopedia/science/tapeworm-anatomy-function.html#ixzz3JWrYThu7

Comment: I am so sorry everyone. Please forgive me.

Answer (score 11):

Is it a:

> baby \ fetus \ embryo?

They could be unwanted if you are too young.

because:

A tiny creature wrapped in slime

> fetuses are wrapped in a placenta

A useful little parasite

> babies grow up to be useful people)

I'll take your food and drink your wine

> fetuses will take anything ingested by the mother

I'll ask for more and you'll oblige.

> the mother cannot deny a fetus from absorbing nutrients from the umbilical cord

Not a tapeworm. No, not quite. 
'Twould be ironic! This is why: 
In tapeworms I as well reside.

> tapeworms can lay eggs which contain tapeworm embryo

Comment: Except babies don't reside in tapeworms.

Comment: Baby tapeworms!

Comment: Mind blown. o__x

Answer (score 7):

Is it a

> worm?

The first stanza fits, and the second stanza:

"In tapeworms I as well reside" could be wordplay since

> "worm" is found in tape**worm**s, and a worm is "not quite" a tapeworm.

Comment: If you spoiler the first part, you may as well spoiler the later part too.

Comment: @Schism good point, edited.

Answer (score 6):

You might be a:

> **Cell**

I'll take your food and drink your wine
I'll ask for more and you'll oblige.

> All cells need nourishment

On tapeworms I as well reside.

> Tapeworms are covered in cells as well

Comment: Not quite. Way to think outside the box.

Comment: This was my guess, too.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a:

> Leech

Leeches are slimy and they can certainly attach themselves to anything.

Comment: Nope! I am so relieved you didn't figure this out in 2 minutes like last time.

Answer (score 1):

You are a:

> Protozoa

This is a gut flora which seems to fit all the clues quite comfortably.

Comment: I had to Google what that was. It is not that thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are a:

> A brain

In my case it is tiny and slimy, and yet very useful. In a way I am my own one, so it can be thought of as a creature. In the case of most people, when their one wants something, they will get it. And I suppose tapeworms have one inside them.

Answer (score 0):

You are a:

> Larva

be definition , larvae of a tapeworm are themselves parasites.